# When is the end behavior of a function a constant?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to think of when the end behavior of a function would be a constant. Could I have an example of when it is? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You mean like $f(x)=\dfrac1x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert, but from what I do know I believe that end behavior of a continuous function will either be constant, oscillate, converge, or go to infinity.

An Example of it being Constant is when the function is defined as something like
f(x) = $\frac{ax}{x}$, where a is some constant. For example f(x) = $\frac{5x}{x}$.

An example of it oscillating would be sin(x), it going to infinity would be f(x) = $x^2$, and and example of it converging would be f(x) = $\frac{1}{x}$.

There might be more cases but none come to mind other than what I specified or something to that effect, does this answer the question?